# Ao colocar a navbar do site como "position: fixed;" ela diminui de tamanho

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tendo um problema no meu código que quando eu defino a posição da navbar como fixed ela simplesmente diminui de tamanho, alguém me ajuda por favor. (Na classe .navbar)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gio PC Fixing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-logo">
            <h1><img src="../midia/logo-gio.png" alt=""></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-options">
            <div>
                <h2>Sobre</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Serviços</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Contato</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="titulo"><h1>Sobre mim</h1></div>


    <div class="sobre">
        <div id="sub">        
            <div>
                <h1>Minha História</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="texto">
            <div>
                <p>
                    Me chamo Giovanni Uchoa, tenho 18 anos e curso Bacharelado em Ciência da Computação. <br>
                Tudo começou quando eu comecei a trabalhar meio período como menor aprendiz no setor de T.I, <br>
                com o tempo eu fui pegando gosto pela informática e pensei: "Porque não fazer o mesmo que eu <br> 
                faço na empresa, mas trabalhando como freelancer?". 
                </p>
                <p>
                A partir desse questionamento eu comecei a produzir alguns folders digitais e criei um perfil <br>
                do GioPcFixing no Instagram para postá-los e divulgar meu trabalho. Comecei então a receber <br>
                alguns serviços e depois não parei mais. <br>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="titulo"><h1>Serviços</h1></div>

    <div class="servicos">
        <div class="imagem">
            <img src="midia/manutencao-corretiva.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="descricao">
            <div>
                <h1>Manutenção Corretiva</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>É onde há a maior procura de serviços,<br>
                    pois esse tipo de manutenção acontece <br>
                    quando há algum defeito no PC e o cliente <br>
                    nos procura para consertar.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="preco">
                <div><h2>Preço: </h2></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="servicos">
        <div class="imagem">
            <img src="midia/manutencao-preventiva.jpg" alt="" width="598" height="450">
        </div>
        <div class="descricao">
            <div>
                <h1>Manutenção Preventiva</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Mais conhecido como o famoso "upgrade", <br>
                    esse serviço é basicamente melhorar o <br>
                    desempenho do computador normalmente <br>
                    através da troca das peças.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="preco">
                <div><h2>Preço: </h2></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="titulo"><h1>Contato</h1></div>

    <div class="contato">
        <div>
            <img src="midia/whatsapp-logo.png" alt="" width="120" height="120">
            <h2>(41) 98879-2727</h2>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="midia/instagram-logo.png" alt="" width="120" height="120">
            <h2>@giopcfixing</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
}

.navbar {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: dashed;
}

.navbar-options {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.navbar-options h2 {
    margin-left: 90px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.navbar-logo {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.titulo h1{
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

.sobre {
    margin-top: 8%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.sobre #sub {
    margin-right: 8%;
}

.sobre #sub h1{
    margin: 2vh;
}

.sobre #texto {
    border-left: dotted;
    text-indent: 5%;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.sobre #texto p {
    margin: 2vh;
}

.servicos {
    display: flex;
}

.imagem {
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.descricao {
    border-left: dashed;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
}

.descricao h1 {
    margin: 5%;
}

.descricao h2 {
    margin: 5%;
}

.preco {
    bottom: 0px;
}

.contato {
    margin-top: 15vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.contato h2 {
    margin-top: 5vh;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Altere pra isso:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* defina uma altura */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: dashed;
}
```

Comment: entendi, obrigado!

mas consegue me explicar o que essas alterações fazem para dar certo?

Comment: O `box-sizing: border-box` faz com que o navegador não calcule margin, padding e etc. Dessa forma, você consegue estilizar melhor. `width: 100%;` vai fazer com que o elemento ocupe 100% de largura da tela. `top: 0;` vai fixar desde o topo da pagina. `left: 0;` vai fixar desde a esquerda(inicio da pagina). `height: 100%;` define uma altura, eu coloquei `auto` ali pq não sei qual valor vc irá usar de altura, então com o valor "auto" ele vai colocar uma altura até onde existe conteudo, pra ficar preenchido.